# Looping through a request.querystring in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, query-string

I am trying to loop through a query string and pull out certain values as in:

```
?ProductID=1234&ProductID=4321&Quantity=1
```

For each value next to ProductID I want to execute some logic.  But I am not sure how to get to the values.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When your query string has more than one value with the same key you can use the [NameValueCollection.GetValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ba5htte.aspx) method which returns a string array:

```
dim productID as string
for each productID  in Page.Request.QueryString.GetValues("ProductID")
  ' do something with productID
next productID
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is some untested psuedo code that should work for the code behind on the page. I hope this helps.

```
dim key as string
dim list as new arraylist()
for each key in Page.Request.QueryString.Keys
 if key = "ProductID" then
   list.add(Page.Request.QueryString(key))
 end if
next key

' do somthing with the list of product id's
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim productID = Request.Querystring("ProductID")
Dim quantity = Request.Querystring("Quantity")
```

Comment: VB doesn't support square brackets, that's C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim sQS as String = Request.QueryString.ToString
For Each eItem In Split(sQS, "&")
Dim sName As String = Left(eItem, InStr(eItem & "=", "=") - 1)
Response.Write(sName _
& " = " & Request.QueryString(sName) _
& "<br>")
Next
```

and this is shorter but based on the same idea

```
For Each Key As String In Request.QueryString.Keys
Response.Write(Key & " = " & Request.QueryString(Key) & "<br>")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.  Only works in VB9.

```
Dim queryString = GetQueryString()
queryString = queryString.SubString(1) 'Remove ?
Dim ids = queryString. _
  Split("&"c). _
  Select(Function(x) x.Split("="c)). _
  Where(Function(x) x(0) = "ProductId" ). _
  Select(Function(x) x(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

For read `Value` of `get Parameter` use `Request.QueryString.Item("param")`