# Retrieve GET variables from URL in ASPX

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

What's the easiest / standard way to retrieve the GET (in URL) variables passed to a .aspx (VB) page?

Comment: Here is an example from SO on looping through the GET postback values. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562943/looping-through-a-request-querystring-in-vb-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562943/looping-through-a-request-querystring-in-vb-net)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the following:

Example URL: http://www.whatever.com?hello=goodbye&goodbye=hello

```
string value = Request.QueryString("hello");
```

Value will be *goodbye*

or

```
foreach(string key in Request.QueryString)
{
    Response.write(Request.QueryString(key))
}
```

Comment: I get a syntax error when using [ ] but not when using ( )

Comment: @ClayNichols same here.  `Request.QueryString["hello"]` doesn't work.  `Request.QueryString("hello")` does.

Comment: I took the liberty to change [ ] to ( ). The latter is VB.NET syntax which the question is about.

Comment: Dec 2020 and this is not working for me. Just getting a blank line when trying to log value. Should this still work?

Answer (score 7):

Look at the Request.QueryString collection

Answer (score 1):

if you have a path :

```
www.stackoverEvan.com/question/directory-lookup.asp?name=Evan&age=16
```

If you do :

```
Hi ,  <%= Request.QueryString("name") %>.  
Your age is  <%= Request.QueryString("age") %>.
```

Output :

Welcome, Evan. Your age is 16

But as your specifying it's in VB the optimal way would be like :

Path :

```
http://localhost/script/directory/NAMES.ASP?Q=Evan&Q=Bhops
```

Code :

```
--- Names.asp --- 
<% 
  For Each item In Request.QueryString("Q") 
    Response.Write Request.QueryString("Q")(item) & "<BR>" 
  Next 
%>
```

Output :

Evan 
Bhops