# Auto populate text fields using URL

Tags: asp.net-webpages, auto-populate

There is an external webpage I use frequently at work that requires I renter generic (non-passord) information before I can use the functionality:

https://online.worksafebc.com/anonymous/employer%20clearance%20letter/default.aspx

I want to create a URL that automatically puts the information into the text fields.  However, I am having a difficult time identifying the names of the variables.  I tried:

.../default.aspx?ctl00$middle$txtLegalName=myname

to no avail.  I'm wondering if this is possible since I am a user and have no access to the code?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: This might be helpful: [Retrieve GET variables from URL in ASPX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033548/retrieve-get-variables-from-url-in-aspx)

Comment: Well, I believe I'm trying to find the real names of the variables associated with the text fields, so that I may create a URL to auto fill those text fields.  I tried using the name attribute of the "Legal Name" text field, which was "ctl00$middle$txtLegalName", but it didn't work when I created the URL using:  ?variable=value, as demonstrated above.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Variables in a query string will not automatically populate a form. That page would need some server-side code to populate the form with variables from the query string. Unfortunately, as you mentioned, you do not have access to the code. You could try to post data to that page using cURL. Maybe the ["Autofill Forms" plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/) would be useful.

Comment: You can't create a URL that does this because ASP.NET expects you to submit the form field data via a different method (adding the data to the URL is called GET method, but you need to use POST method). It is possible to do something similar to what you want but will be more complicated and needs to be done with client side script or server side coding.