# How to pass variables to another page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I actually got it to work using the code below.Thanks to all who gave me their inputs, but have to say I had difficulties getting it to work properly. Hope it will be helpful to somebody else who is new in javascript.

```
function SelectedRow() {
            (function () {
                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener('load', run, false);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    window.attachEvent('onload', run);
                }

                function run() {
                    var table = document.getElementById('alternativeCableTable');
                    table.onclick = function (event) {
                        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
                        while (target && target.nodeName != 'TR') { 
                            target = target.parentElement;
                        }              
                        var cells = target.cells;              
                        if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') {
                            return;
                        }
                        var stockcode = document.getElementById('stockcode');
                        var wiretype = document.getElementById('wiretype');
                        var wirelength = document.getElementById('wirelength');
                        var terminalA = document.getElementById('termA');
                        var sealA = document.getElementById('sealA');
                        var terminalB = document.getElementById('termB');
                        var sealB = document.getElementById('sealB');
                        stockcode.value = cells[0].innerHTML;
                        wiretype.value = cells[1].innerHTML;
                        wirelength.value = cells[2].innerHTML;
                        terminalA.value = cells[3].innerHTML;
                        sealA.value = cells[4].innerHTML;
                        terminalB.value = cells[5].innerHTML;
                        sealB.value = cells[6].innerHTML;
                        alert("The select data is sent to print page");
                        window.open("http://10.19.13.67/ReworkLabels/PrintLabelPage.aspx?stockcode=" + decodeURIComponent(stockcode.value) + "&wiretype=" + decodeURIComponent(wiretype.value) + "&wirelength=" + decodeURIComponent(wirelength.value)
                       + "&terminalA=" + decodeURIComponent(terminalA.value) + "&sealA=" + decodeURIComponent(sealA.value) + "&terminalB=" + decodeURIComponent(terminalB.value) + "&sealB=" + decodeURIComponent(sealB.value),"_blank");

                    };

                }

            })();
        }
```

Comment: the string `+` operator calls `toString()` method. You need to get some way to get the value from `f1` that you actually want to send.

Comment: and i think that they may be basically `cells[0].innerHTML`

Comment: You need to use `f1.value` instead of `f1` and same with `f2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
 window.open("http://Testing/ReworkLabels/Default.aspx?"+f1.value+"&"+f2.value,"my window");
```

instead.

Comment: thanks it does work,now i have two textboxes in Default.aspx and i need to know how to put f1.value in textbox1 and f2.value in textbox2?

Answer (score 2):

Use **Local Storage**, instead of passing URL parameters and/or cookies, as the later two have a lot of limitations.

See an example how to do so in http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2013/04/how-to-use-local-storage-for-javascript/

If you need these values for some reason server-side, then you could utilize JSON serialization to pass the values as POST parameters. (Or just HTML forms with hidden inputs; Do not forget to put name attributes on the html form elements that needs to be submitted to server.)

EDIT: On second reading of your question, it looks like you just need 2 simple string values. In this case check the **value** properties of the two input elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement

Also you might want to give names to these GET parameters, e.g.

```
window.open("http://Testing/ReworkLabels/Default.aspx?f1="+encodeURIComponent(f1.value)+"&f2="+encodeURIComponent(f2.value),"my window");
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent for more information about encodeURIComponent function.

See [Retrieve GET variables from URL in ASPX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033548/retrieve-get-variables-from-url-in-aspx) in order to read these parameters in the target ASP.NET page.

Also make sure to not print their values directly (but properly escaped), to avoid cross site scripting (XSS) vulnerability.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx and [How do you avoid XSS vulnerabilities in ASP.Net (MVC)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3955658/how-do-you-avoid-xss-vulnerabilities-in-asp-net-mvc)