# How to pass a variable from html to aspx?

Tags: html, asp.net

I want to pass the variable from **html** page to a hidden field in **aspx** page, I have a **aspx** form with code

```
    <div id="divFrameHolder" style="display: none">
       <iframe  src="inner/RegSelect.html"name="myIframe" id="myIframe" width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0" onload="hideLoading()"> 
<asp:HiddenField   ID = "hidField"   runat="server"  value = " " /> 
     </iframe>
    </div>
```

and `RegSelect.html` has this code

```
<div id="tabs">

        <ul>

            <li style="font-family:'b nazanin';  font-weight:bold"><a onclick="use();" href="site"><i class="fa fa-picture-o fa-5x"></i><br />سایت</a></li>
            <li style="font-family: 'b nazanin'; font-weight: bold"><a onclick="use();" href="stor"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart  fa-5x"></i><br />فروشگاه</a></li>
            <li style="font-family: 'b nazanin'; font-weight: bold"><a onclick="use();" href="blog"><i class="fa fa-comments  fa-5x"></i><br />وبلاگ</a></li>

        </ul>

        <section class="tabs-content" style="width:100%">

            <div id="site" style="width:100%" >

            </div>


            <div id="stor">

            </div>
            <div id="blog">

            </div>
</section>

    </div>
<script>

        $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
            var f = $(this).attr('href');
            alert(f);
            window.opener.location.href = "RegForm.aspx?" + "val=" + f
            //var c = $('#myIframe').contents().find('#HF1').val();
            //alert(c);
            //alert($('#myIframe #HF1').val());
            //$('  #HF1').val(f);          
        });
    </script>
```

Now, I want get `var f` in **aspx** page? Can I get the variable from **html** page into **aspx** page?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. It seems you are asking how to _set_ a value of an `input` field from some _client side_ event which makes it no different than any _client side_ method of doing so, *vs* obtaining data from a `request` - query string or POST data payload....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Request.QueryString to get the value of an URL parameter

[Retrieve GET variables from URL in ASPX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033548/retrieve-get-variables-from-url-in-aspx)

Comment: i use html page and i want send var f to aspx

Comment: so you want send the value of the "f" variable to your server side?

Comment: i want send value of the "f" variable to aspx page in a hiddenfield

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to pass a variable from the html page in the IFrame to a hidden field in the page containing the IFrame.

Accessing IFrame content using jQuery as explained here: [how to access iFrame parent page using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-access-iframe-parent-page-using-jquery)

Note: ASP.NET WebForms has a setting that determines how ID's are generated for a control.  [See Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx)  Make sure your hidden field's id mode is static.

Also understand that ASP.NET generates ID's to prevent collisions.  Use an ID for your hidden field that you know will be unique on the page.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidField" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" value=" " />
```

Use this to access the hidden field in the aspx page:

```
   $('#tabs a').click(function (e) {
        var f = $(this).attr('href');
        alert(f);
        window.opener.location.href = "RegForm.aspx?" + "val=" + f

        $('#hidField', window.parent.document).val(f);

        //var c = $('#myIframe').contents().find('#HF1').val();
        //alert(c);
        //alert($('#myIframe #HF1').val());
        //$('  #HF1').val(f);          
    });
```

Note that hidField needs to be a dom element in the containing aspx page.

**ASPX**

```
<div id="divFrameHolder" style="display: none">
   <iframe  src="inner/RegSelect.html"name="myIframe" id="myIframe" width="100%" height="200px" frameborder="0" onload="hideLoading()"> 
 </iframe>

 <input type="hidden" id="hidField" />

</div>
```

Comment: Please provide an updated code sample of what you have tried.

Comment: Add ClientIDMode="Static" to the hidden field control.  See revised answer.

Comment: use this code after click iframe gone and i see not found :(

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. Try updating your example.